# Problems with has_many associations searchkick

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, searchkick

I have probelm with use Searchkick with associated models.
I would like to be able to do a search that is able to list all the model information from the List model.
For example
"frederic 2020-01-01"

I would like this to return the fields related to frederic (which in this case is an account_name) and the date, which is related to model post

Can someone help me?
The Models:

```
   class List < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick 

    has_many :people

end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts
  belongs_to :list
  searchkick
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :person

  searchkick
end


class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  searchkick
end
```

And on List_controller:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index

    if params[:keywords].present?

      @lists = List.search(params[:keywords], operator: "or")
    else 
      @lists = List.all
    end
  end
end
```

My schema.rb

```
  create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "social_network"
    t.string "name_account"
    t.integer "person_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["person_id"], name: "index_accounts_on_person_id"
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "list_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["list_id"], name: "index_people_on_list_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "post_text"
    t.date "date"
    t.string "link"
    t.integer "account_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_posts_on_account_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "accounts", "people"
  add_foreign_key "people", "lists"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "accounts"
end
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you basically want to achieve free text search over All your models and return the relevant list connected to your search ?
If this is the case I would recommend implementing elastic search and using it as your search engine for free text. In case you prefer and keep use SQL think about creating a new column for List - "tags" and you can keep there all the information that you want to "search" and keep it updated. Otherwise you can just do an SQL through All the tables with "or" between all columns (not very recommended - slow and not scalable)

Comment: I tried to use Elastic Search, but I was unable to list all content for search by free text, do you know how I list all content for models to consult? I tried map, but doesn't works

Comment: How can I, from List, make a "free text" query relating the fields of the other models?

Comment: You don't. When you Index the main model - in your case is probably List. You index it with ALL the information.

Comment: My main model is List, how I index it? I don't understand

Comment: When you have a more complicated structure/schema, you need to customize the as_indexed_json method - or perform the indexing separately, on your own. For example, let's have an Article model, which has_many Comments, Authors and Categories. We might want to define the serialization like this:
def as_indexed_json(options={})
  self.as_json(
    include: { categories: { only: :title},
               authors:    { methods: [:full_name], only: [:full_name] },
               comments:   { only: :text }
             })
end

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model